# vb datagridview columntype change on edit

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

is there a method of setting up my datagridview to show me textboxcolumns until editmode is entered? At which time I will swap some textboxcolumns for bound comboboxcolumns. And at the end of validation/exit edit mode I can swap back?

If there's a method of doing this please share some links to examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to switch DataGridView ColumnTypes like that.  Sounds like a bad time.

Is your goal to have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that does not display the ComboBox dropdown button when it's not being edited?  If so, there are two options:

1. Set the column's [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaystyleforcurrentcellonly.aspx) to True.
2. Create your own DGV column based on the ComboBox by extending DataGridViewTextBoxCell.  MSDN has a great article for doing this with the Calendar control [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going for. Had to set displaystyle to "nothing" for the desired effect. Now if I could just figure out my binding problems

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can. In the properties of the datagridview you can drill down to the column proprieties and switch the datatype to combo box. Very straight forward and easy.

Comment: my post was related to swapping column types at runtime. Your answer only applies to design time.